# What regex for matching words with keyword '('?

Tags: c#, regex

In my c# code I need to get a word if the words before match specific words:

```
var match= Regex.Match(someLine, @"^(FIRST WORDS) (\w+) (SECOND WORDS | PROBLEM KEYWORD \() (\w+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var neededWord= match.Groups[4].Value;
```

If the string equals "FIRST WORDS SOME WORDS PROBLEM KEYWORD (SOMETHING AGAIN)", I would like to get 'SOMETHING' as my needed word. But this does not work. It returns an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Maybe this link can help you. I'm not great with RegEx but every time I need to use it I use this to emulate the results

Answer (score 2):

### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM5gK8)

```
^FIRST WORDS[^\(]+\(([^\)]+)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4TSM8Vpb3hi18P4u)

**Description**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
FIRST WORDS matches the characters FIRST WORDS literally (case sensitive)
[^\(]+ match a single character not present in the list below
    Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \( matches the character ( literally
\( matches the character ( literally
1st Capturing group ([^\)]+)
    [^\)]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \) matches the character ) literally
\) matches the character ) literally
```

***Note:** if you need only the word SOMETHING I can edit the RegEx, also `Group 1` will contain your requested results.*